# Update MVC ViewModel List from the client using either jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a viewmodel along the lines of

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        Locations = new List<Location>();
    }

    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Location> Locations {get;set}
}

public class Location
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string LocationName {get;set;}
}
```

The class Person is used to populate a simple view that displays the Person details and below the list of Locations.

I have created a button that adds a new Location by creating a new div, populating html and then appending it to a div containing all of the Locations.

```
$('#Locations').append(newItem.html());      <---- newItem - contains new div

<div id="Locations">
    <div class="location">
    </div>
    ...
    ...
    <div class="location">
    </div>
</div>
```

All of this works, but on posting back to the controller, the new locations are not passed back in the viewmodel.

How is this done?

Can I see the data in any other way?

I have used ajax before, but cannot use it on this specific site.

Comment: Can you add the newItem content? Especially the name and ID part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed code to use Ajax call, then on return add the relevant html to add hidden fields required.

Answer (score 1):

Rico Suter has a great blog about this at https://blog.rsuter.com/asp-net-mvc-how-to-implement-an-edit-form-for-an-entity-with-a-sortable-child-collection/.
The extension methods he created are really easy to use and customize.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you're not actually submitting any of the new locations back - you need to encapsulate them into hidden input fields (as well as the divs for displaying the information to the user) so that when you resubmit your form data, the new locations are included in the request and can be captured by your controller action.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to bind an array when you post back. The general form to format your HTML input tags so that they will reconstitute as a list when you bind in post is described in several places such as [Phil Hack - Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/). So if you structure your DOM changes to adhere to the format described, your extra rows should bind on post.